# Rails: path of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have inside `app` a directory called `csv` and inside this dir I have a file called `names.csv`
I want to use `File.read(path:string)` function to read the file.
what is the relative path to the file?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'csv', 'names.csv')
File.read(file)
```

Comment: There's no need to use `File.join` because `Rails.root` is a `Pathname` object. Just do this: `Rails.root + "app/csv/names.csv"`

Comment: In particular, File.join does NOT protect you from one or more of the path parts being '..', and will happily produce a path like 'app/csv/../controllers/users_controller.rb' if given  File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'csv', '../controllers/user_controller.rb') or  File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'csv', '..', 'controllers', 'user_controller.rb')

Comment: To @RyanBigg's comment: Every time you use back or forward slash in a path, you make your app OS-specific. `File.join` is the safer way to go

Answer (score 18):

You should do: `Rails.root.join "app", "csv", "names.csv"`

Rails.root returns a PathName object. PathName has a `join` method which takes any number of arguments and appends it to the pathname to create the new path.

Read on PathName#join here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-join

Answer (score 9):

`Rails.root` points to the top folder of your rails project, so the path would be:

```
File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app','csv','names.csv'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for above answers, It also worked this way for me:

```
"#{Rails.root}/public/spreadsheets/file_name.xlsx"
```

Comment: It makes path OS-specific

Answer (score 0):

For me is a great idea to make variable for folder path and for every file add variable with file name like that:

```
source = File.join(Rails.root, 'sources', 'folder_with_files')
    
file1 = File.read("#{source}/file1.txt")
file2 = File.read("#{source}/file2.txt")
...
```