# getting the server path of the image in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `file field` control for upload image like below:

```
<%= form_for(:ImageUpload, :html => { :id => "imageupload" }) do |f| %>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <%= file_field( "upload", "datafile") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="92%">
            <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <div class="button" style="margin-right:60px;">
                    <%= f.submit "Next", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

controller page:

```
  def create

    get_img_path = params[:upload][:datafile].path
    @blah = get_img_path

    render 'new'
  end
```

And I want to get sever path of the uploaded image and also want to change the server path of the image into this `app/assets/upload` because I want to store the uploaded image at this path `app/assets/uploaded`. 
Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `Paperclip` or `Carrierwave` gem to handle this.

Paperclip - [Click Here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Carrierwave - [Click Here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

To get the path you can do this

```
file_path = params[:upload].blank? ? "" : params[:upload].path
```

Comment: is there any other way to getting the server path of the image.

Comment: but getting error "undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: only `params[:upload].path` not `params[:upload][:datafile].path`

Comment: gets me error "undefined method `path' for "{\"datafile\"=>\"index.jpg\"}":String" and when i am using this "params[:upload][:datafile]" then it gets me error "undefined method `path' for "index.jpg":String"

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use Paperclip, but if you want a totally "native" solution, why not try [this recommendation](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=22071):

```
path = params[:file].path
```

---

Looking at your updates, it seems you're hitting an issue by only accessing the string element of the path. The solution to that would be to [translate it into a `File` object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#M000023), which you'll then be able to load the path for

You can [see this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm) on how to go about it:

```
#app/models/file.rb
Class File < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
  end
end
```

This is how you save the file; but if you wanted to get the path, you'd still use the `.path` method, except you need to do it on a `File` object

To do this, I looked at [several resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445498/rails-model-file-path), and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147277/rails-path-of-file):

```
file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'csv', 'names.csv')
file.path
```

Comment: I have already seen this link "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm" but I have a database app.

Comment: Yep, doesn't the db save the file? How are you saving the file currently?

Comment: yet i am not saving the file, but my idea is that "I want to get sever path of the uploaded image and change the server path of the image into this app/assets/upload because I want to store the uploaded image at this path app/assets/uploaded" that's why I want to get the server path of the image.

Comment: So you're not saving the file, but you want to store it in the `uploaded` path? That sounds like saving to me?